# Is there any benefit in not binding a solution file (to tfs) whilst keeping project files bound?

Tags: .net

I've seen quite a few visual studio solutions where the actual solution file is *not bound* but the projects *are bound* to source control.

**Question:**

Is there any benefit in this approach when it comes to building on an integration server?

So far I've taken the approach that it must have been an oversight and just bound the solution, then committed to source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are working at the same product/project in a team and everybody needs to get latest, modify and check in changes, the solution file .sln should also be committed or other people will be unable to retrieve it.

user specific files like solutionname.suo do not need to be checked in because every user locally has his/her settings and this should not be persisted in the TFS server.

if the solution file is not checked-in and a developer adds a new project inside a solution, other developers will get the new project but will need to add it manually in their local solution file.

we check in projects and solutions with nornal results. did this in SVN, Mercurial, TFS, always same pattern and always satisfied.